# Error: Cannot find module '/.../...Part-3/index.js' root@123: Why this Error

Tags: javascript, express

I am getting this Error, Actually,I just started with Express Js?

```
root@123:/.../...part-3# node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/.../...Part-3/index.js'
root@123:/.../...part-3#
```

Comment: Please share the full code and not just the error

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe there is no `index.js` in `part-3`? Or it's a capitalization issue somewhere, the error says `Part-3` while the directory is called `part-3`...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you try to start the server outside the project directory using node. Therefore Start the server from your project directory.